# Can not open cpp excutable after compilation

Tags: c++, g++

I am having problem executing a cpp file after compilation.
Here is the text output and how I compile it and try to run.

```
coovi@coovi-Surface-Book:~/HW9$ g++ -Wall main.cpp -g -o main
coovi@coovi-Surface-Book:~/HW9$ chmod +x main
coovi@coovi-Surface-Book:~/HW9$ ./main
Can not open the file
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76762/discussion-on-question-by-meha-felix-can-not-open-cpp-excutable-after-compilatio).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're having problems with your source code.  It's executing.  **The compiling commands were executed correctly.**  The error is being generated by your program that when it runs.

You'll have to debug your source code to fix it.

It's great practice to code with a text editor.  But you might consider using a GUI such as [Eclipse](http://eclipse.org/downloads) to assist in the debugging of your source when it grows a little big for handing.

Comment: It still doesn't work, in try to Uninstall and reinstall gcc and gpp. But same thing. Is there anything suplementary file I need to install? I am using Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Copy your text from [the link you posted](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-DLa1NDIJgU6tlM6w62wNF3qHx78QM_L) and paste it into Gedit.  Then compile it.

Comment: That is the process ther worked for me as well as Egon Stetmann.